# Reusing same function in different ways

Tags: java

I have got class like this

```
class Calculate {
    int operation(int a, int b){
         return Math.max(a,b);
    }
    int calc(int a, int b){
        int x=100+a*b;
        int y=a+a*b;
        retun operation(x,y);
    }
    int calc1(int a, int b){
        int x=100+a*b;
        int y=b+a*b;
        return operation(x,y);
    }
}
```

Now I make two objects of this class as
`Calculate obj1=new Calculate();`
`Calculate obj2=new Calculate();`
I want function operation of Class calculate to act like returning maximum of two values for obj1, and return minimum of two values for obj2. Can this be done? 
I could only think of creation two different classes Calculate1 and Calculate2 and defining operation as maximum in Calculate1 and minimum in Calculate2 and defining rest thing as same as it is. I hope some easier method also exist without defining two classes.

Comment: hmm in other languages you could have a "function object" (delegate in C#, function pointer in C, function variable in python,ruby,haskell), in java I would look for an interface and anonymous classes

Comment: Can you please provide the edited code for given sample code? It would be great.

Comment: @niceman Java added [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) in 1.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `operation` method.

If you don't want to create explicit sub-classes, you can do this with anonymous classes :

```
Calculate obj1=new Calculate();
Calculate obj2=new Calculate() {
    int operation(int a, int b){
        return Math.min(a,b);
    }
};

obj1.operation(a,b) // calculates maximum
obj2.operation(a,b) // calculates minimum
```

Comment: This works well in OP's example because his other methods reference `operation` which will also use the overriden method instead.

Comment: It would probably be more elegant, or at least symmetrical, to make operation abstract.

Comment: It might. It seems to depend on the situation. Suppose that the standard of Calculate objects is that they find the max, and there are many Calculate objects in the program. If for some reason one Calculate object needs to be the exception to the rule, Eran's answer is more suitable. If there is no standard for the method at all, making the method abstract would work better. And if there is no standard for the class, then the entire Calculate class would be abstract and subclasses should be made to perform various operations.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the operation to the constructor as [an `IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html), for example:

```
class Calculate {

  private final IntBinaryOperator op;

  public Calculate(IntBinaryOperator operator) {
    this.op = operator;
  }

  int operation(int a, int b) {
    return op.applyAsInt(a, b);
  }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
Calculate c1 = new Calculate(Math::max);
Calculate c2 = new Calculate(Math::min);
```

And adding an operation is easy - say you want the sum instead of min or max:

```
Calculate c3 = new Calculate((x, y) -> x + y);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an OOP concept called **Inheritance**

```
public abstract class Calculate {

    public abstract int operation(int a, int b);

    int calc(int a, int b){
        int x=100+a*b;
        int y=a+a*b;
        return operation(x,y);
    }

    int calc1(int a, int b){
        int x=100+a*b;
        int y=b+a*b;
        return operation(x,y);
    }

}

class Obj1 extends Calculate{

    @Override
    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
    }

}

class Obj2 extends Calculate{

    @Override
    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    }

}
```

Each new class implements it own method of operation.

Comment: This isn't abstraction. This is inheritance. Abstraction is the concept of hiding complex code outside of current scope so that classes don't need or care to know how other classes function.

Comment: the OP said "I could only think of defining two classes" so obviously the OP wanted to avoid creating classes :)

Comment: I think he just did not want to repeat the same code (method calc and calc1) in two different classes

Answer (score 3):

You can have something like this :

```
interface Operation
{
    int operation(int a,int b);
}
class Calculate
{
    Operation operation;
    //rest of class
}
```

you use the class like this :

```
Calculate obj1=new Calculate();
obj1.operation=(a,b)->Math.max(a,b);
Calculate obj2=new Calculate();
obj2.operation=(a,b)->Math.max(a,b);
```

### A couple of notes :

1. you can add a constructor that takes `Operation` to initialize `operation` variable.
2. you should probably have a `call` method in `Calculate` class and make `operation` private for better encapsulation
3. `operation` is probably better to be final
4. This solution may not be as straight forward as other languages but it's the best I can have.
   Languages that supported functions as first class citizens from the beginning would make that easier because you can have a function variable which you assign,pass,return just like any variable.

In java we have to use interfaces and anonymous classes to support this, the lambda expressions above were added to java 8 so for java 7 we would write the above like this :

```
Calculate obj1=new Calculate();
obj1.operation=new Operation{
                   @Override
                   int operation(int a,int b)
                   {
                       return Math.max(a,b);
                   }
               }
//code for obj2
```

### Edit

You can replace `Operation` with [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) introduced in java 8(specifically `IntBinaryOperator`).

Comment: That is strategy pattern

Comment: @OlegKurbatov yes I discovered that after I saw your answer,hence the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strategy pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to achieve your goal.

Basically you want externalize `operation` to an interface and specify the object that implements the interface (with min or max) in constructor of `Calculate`.

This approach gives you most flexible solution that is proof to changes of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your class as follows:

```
class Calculate {
    private boolean calcMax;

    public Calculate(boolean calcMax){
        this.calcMax = calcMax;
    }

    int operation(int a, int b){
         return calcMax ? Math.max(a,b) : Math.min(a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would do the work by initializing global variable. But same work can be done by object oriented concept(not using global variable)?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Calculate {

public int a=0;
public int b=0;

public int maxVal = 0;
public int minVal = 0; 

public Calculate(int a, int b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;

    this.maxVal=Math.max(a,b);


    this.minVal = Math.min(a, b);

}
}
```

Assuming you are finding the mins and max of the same variables...